# How to write a macro that finds a cell based on length?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel and trying to find a way to search through a column to find a 4-character ID. The spreadsheet is sorted so that all of the information falls under corresponding ID's and to pull out the ID's I need to find the cells with 4 alphanumeric characters in a column.

I have been trying to use .Find, however there is no what:= to search because the characters are all different but only the length is the same. Also, I don't believe I can run a do until loop as I need to call the macro multiple times to retrieve all the ID's that will be present in a column whereas I think the do until loop will just keep giving back the first 4 character ID, although I might be incorrect.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd argue that a "do until" loop can perform any action within the given circumstance - however you're going to need to be more specific before anyone here can assist you.

Comment: I'd argue that there is a `What:=` to search (i.e. `What:="????"`)

Comment: Can you show some Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might help you. Assuming you have a single contiguous range of cells, some of which contain a 4 character code, you can do

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1:A6")

For Each c In r.Cells
  If Len(c) = 4 Then
    Debug.Print "cell ", c.Address(), " had four characters: ", c.Value()
  End If
Next c
End Sub
```

When I run this on a spreadsheet where the first 6 cells in column A are

```
This
is
a
list
of
words
```

The output in the debug window is

```
cell $A$1 had four characters: this
cell $A$4 had four characters: list
```

This is for inspiration only, as your problem was really not very well described. Can you take it from here?